# How to solve that?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals, factoring, quartics

I have no idea about how to solve the following:
$$\sqrt[4]{13x+1} + \sqrt[4]{4x-1} = 3\sqrt[4]{x}$$

Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: Start by raising both sides to the fourth power.

Comment: Well, you move all the terms that are linear in $x$ to one side, so that all the radicals are on the other side.  Then raising to the fourth power again gives you a fourth degree polynomial in $x$.  But in this case, it looks pretty messy.  I imagine the answer posted by Michael Rozenberg is easier, but I don't quite follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t^4=4-\frac1x$

$$\sqrt[4]{13x+1} + \sqrt[4]{4x-1} = 3\sqrt[4]{x}\iff \sqrt[4]{17-t^4} + t = 3 \iff 17-t^4=(3-t)^4$$

$$\iff 2 t^4 - 12 t^3 + 54 t^2 - 108 t + 64=0 \iff 2 (t - 1) (t - 2) (t^2 - 3 t + 16)=0$$

thus

- $t=2 \implies 16=4-\frac1x \implies x=-\frac1{12}$ (complex solution)
- $t=1 \implies 1=4-\frac1x \implies x=\frac13$ (real solution)

Comment: $x=-1/12$ is inadmissible, since you'd be taking the fourth root of a negative number in the original equation.

Comment: @saulspatz yes of course, I've let as a possible solution with complex

Comment: Sure, but then the complex roots of $t^2-3t+16$ give another two complex solutions.

Comment: @saulspatz x=-1/12 is a real solution which requires complex roots, I can eliminate if it is not clear!

Comment: No problem, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sqrt[4]{13x+1}=a$ and $ \sqrt[4]{4x-1}=b$.

Thus, $a\geq0$ and $b\geq0$ and $$a+b=3\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4}{17}},$$ which is homogeneous and
$$\frac{a^4-1}{13}=\frac{b^4+1}{4}.$$
The first gives after squaring of the both sides:
$$(a-2b)(2a-b)(16a^2+23ab+16b^2)=0.$$
Since $16a^2+23ab+16b^2=0$ gives $a=b=0,$ which is impossible,

we get $(a-2b)(2a-b)=0$ only. I think now you can end it.

Comment: Once again, do not post a pseudo-answer with the intent to make it an answer after you post it, and then rush to edit within 5 min of posting, to make it look, in the edit history, as though you posted the answer all at once.  Rather, *actually do post the answer you intend to post,* only after you've formulated it in its entirety.  I am so sorry you feel so desperate to post first!

Comment: Most users here don't try to game the system by posting something incomprehensible to the OP, then taking 8 minutes to actually complete the post, as you do.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean when you say, "The first gives by squaring of the sides".  What is "the first"?  And do you mean "raise both sides to the fourth power"?  I don't see where squaring would simplify anything.

Comment: @saulspatz I mean squaring twice: $17(a+b)^4=81(a^4+b^4).$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What' s "The first" and how do you square both sides?

Comment: We got the system with two equations. I said about the first equation of this system. See please better my solution.